# import xlsx data into sql server 2008

Tags: sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005

I am able to insert data from xls file in sql server but not able to insert from xlsx file (office 2010) .

the reason behind this for doing this file having more then five lac records and in xls the file limit is 65000 approx records.

Pleas suggest how can i insert data from xlsx in sql server 2008.

Regards,
Manoj

Answer (score 3):

After my complete night search over the internet surfing, i found that there was a simple mistake of "\" without quotes. there is no need to go for 64 bit.
i am running windows 7 (32 bit), having MS Office 2007 installed.

```
SELECT * FROM OPENROWSET('Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0',
                         'Excel 12.0;Database=D:countrybook.xlsx;HDR=YES',
                         'SELECT * FROM [country$]')
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you have the correct connection string?

```
Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=c:\myFolder\myExcel2007file.xlsx;Extended 
Properties="Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=YES
```

You can see more information [here](http://www.sqlteam.com/forums/topic.asp?TOPIC_ID=122809), [here](http://www.connectionstrings.com/excel-2007) and [here](http://www.sqlteam.com/forums/topic.asp?TOPIC_ID=49926&whichpage=17#445330)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks guys.. its work for me..

```
SELECT * FROM OPENROWSET('Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0',
                     'Excel 12.0;Database=<Your Path of .xslx file>;HDR=YES',
                     'SELECT * FROM [<select which sheet>]')
```